# The circuit was designed to have a -10 gain, but in the PSpice is -5. Why is this happening?

Tags: mosfet, simulation, pspice

I'm doing a project where I need to design an amplifier (shown below) with a BSS100 transistor:

[image]

With the following characteristics:

\$ Av \$ gain = -10
\$Vcc = 5V \$
\$ Rin > 500 \Omega \$
\$ R1 + R2 = 10k\Omega\$
\$ C1 = C3 = 2.2\mu F \$

And using this equation to calculate k from BSS100:

[image]

Here is what I did so far:

From the datasheet I used this to get Vth = 1.5, since the tip was to get the typical value:

[image]

And this to get Id and Vgs:

[image]

The tip was to use the 'd' curve. Does anyone know why this curve?

I calculated k ~= 0.125.

So I designed this circuit:
[image]

The graph this simulation resulted:

[image]

Anyone could explain this graph? Why is with this gain and not -10?

Comment: Can you share the BSS100 PSpice model? For what Id value did you calculated 10V/V ??

Comment: I used Id and Vgs in a configuration that I don't know how is it in english, but I think is something like maximum symmetric. The Vgs was 1.95V dont dont really know the Id, but it is close to 0.22. The BSS100 it the /PLP/PHIL_FET

Comment: You've got a different result because your MOSFET in the simulation will have a different value for the K factor and Vt. You can try to check it in the simulation. Apply 3.5V at the gate and see if you get 0.25A of a drain current (short-out Rd resistor.)

Comment: Did you intend that \$I_D \approx 5.3\mathrm{mA}\$ and \$V_{GS} - V_{th} \approx 0.46\mathrm{V}\$?

Comment: You're using the 3.5V load line, but you look to be biasing it at just under 2V.  Maybe R1 and R2 are switched?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's work backwards on this. What do we know?

From your simulation, we can tell that \$I_D = \frac{5\mathrm V - 4.057 \mathrm V}{174\Omega} \approx 5.3 \mathrm{mA}\$. We also know that \$V_{GS} = 1.96\mathrm V\$ and that the gain is about 5.

The gain is given by the formula \$A_V = g_m R_D\$. So \$g_m = \frac {A_V}{R_D} = \frac 5 {174\Omega} \approx 28.7\mathrm{mS}\$.

The transconductance is given by \$g_m = \frac{2I_D}{V_{GS} - V_{th}}\$. So \$V_{th} = V_{GS} - \frac{2I_D}{g_m} = 1.96\mathrm{V} - 2\frac{5.3\mathrm{mA}}{28.7\mathrm{mS}} \approx 1.59\mathrm V\$. The simulation includes channel length modulation and other effects, so we expect a small difference from the typical 1.5V. We only really care about \$V_{GS} - V_{th}\$, but it's good to check all our assumptions.

Finally, we can plug our threshold voltage into the drain current formula:

$$I_D \approx \frac 1 2 k (V_{GS} - V{th})^2$$
$$5.3\mathrm{mA} \approx \frac 1 2 k (1.96\mathrm V - 1.59\mathrm V)^2$$
$$k \approx 77.4 \frac{\mathrm{mA}}{\mathrm{V^2}}$$

You got \$k \approx 125 \frac{\mathrm{mA}}{\mathrm{V^2}}\$.

The datasheet shows some typical \$I_D\$ vs. \$V_{DS}\$ curves for different values of \$V_{GS}\$. The 3.5V curve (d) seems like a nice middle value, so let's try that. At \$V_{DS} = 4\mathrm V\$, we see that \$I_D = 250\mathrm{mA}\$. Using \$V_{th} = 1.5 \mathrm V\$, we can calculate:

$$250\mathrm {mA} = \frac 1 2 k (3.5\mathrm V - 1.5 \mathrm V)^2$$
$$k \approx 125 \frac{\mathrm{mA}}{\mathrm{V^2}}$$

Huh. That's weird. What about curve (a) which uses \$V_{GS} = 2\mathrm V\$, almost exactly what you have in your sim?

$$25 \mathrm {mA} = \frac 1 2 k (2.0\mathrm V - 1.5\mathrm V)^2$$
$$k \approx 200 \frac{\mathrm{mA}}{\mathrm{V^2}}$$

Even worse. At this point, I start asking questions about the model and the datasheet. The BSS100 datasheet I found when Googling gave a typical Vth of 1.4V, and I calculated an even higher k from its graph. The part seems to be obsolete, so there are only archived copies from 1996. Tell your professor to find a new MOSFET. :-)

Either there's something wrong with your PSpice model, or the more detailed simulation is just that much different from the simple formulas, or something weird is going on. (Or I messed up somewhere.) Either way, this is a great example of why you shouldn't rely on transistor parameters when designing circuits. :-)